# WPF Custom Control Work by itself but not as part of another control

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls

I have a WPF Custom Control that I use to display images.

There is a list view which is bound to an observable collection of database entities, which is subsequently converted into an image by virtue of a value converter.

When I drag the control onto a windows forms project (using a WPF Host control) it works perfectly when assigning the observable collection behind a list. I have tested this and it updates correctly and does everything i need it to.

HOWEVER

I would like to have three such controls displaying related images so I created a second control which simply grouped the three original controls into a stack panel.

I created a method for each that updates the images property.

```
 public void ChangeSearchResults(List<ItemImage> items)
 {
      SearchResultsImageViewer.ItemImages = new ObservableCollection<ItemImage>(items);
 }
```

However I simply cant get the images to show.

There seems to be a difference between viewing a control directly and viewing a control as a child control.

I am pretty sure it is not the element host in winforms as the control works well by itself.

Is there something I am not realising?

This is the Xaml for the list view

```
        <!--  Sets the template for the data to be displayed  -->
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>

            <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel>
                        <!--  Defines the actual image being displayed  -->
                        <Image x:Name="ItemImageControl"
                               Width="100"
                               Height="200"
                               Margin="1"
                               HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                               VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                               Cursor="Hand"
                               Source="{Binding .,
                                                Converter={StaticResource imageConverter}}" />

                        <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                   FontWeight="Bold"
                                   Text="{Binding .,
                                                  Converter={StaticResource groupNameConverter}}" />
                    </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
```

**EDIT - this is the user control XAML**

```
<UserControl x:Class="Project.CustomControls.ctrlImageCollection"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:CustomControls="clr-namespace:Project.CustomControls"
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             mc:Ignorable="d">
        <StackPanel>
            <CustomControls:ctrlImageViewer x:Name="ShortlistImageViewer" />
            <CustomControls:ctrlImageViewer x:Name="SearchResultsImageViewer" />
            <CustomControls:ctrlImageViewer x:Name="GroupImageViewer" />
        </StackPanel>
</UserControl>
```

Comment: How you had differentiated your two diffrent image controls !!!

Comment: I have given them different names?

Answer (score 0):

With using

```
...
Source={Binding ., Converter={StaticResource imageConverter}}" />
```

you bind to the current UserControl. When you use your ListView alone, it is bound to the UserControl containing the ListView and will work.

If you put your ListView UserControl into another UserControl its values get bound to its parent UserControl, not longer "own" UserControl.

Try this:

Go to your ListView UserControl xaml.cs and set the DataContext to itself.

```
//...
DataContext = this;
//...
```